# Create a tooltip on bootstrap multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add a tooltip on a multiselect dropdown menu that I created using the Bootstrap-select jQuery plugin...

This is the way I defined my select in HTML...

```
<select id="dropDownList" 
        class="selectpicker" 
        title="Show Level" 
        multiple data-actions-box="true">
</select>
```

This dropdown gets populated at runtime with a JSON file and the header of the dropdown is the title that I set in the HTML, 'Show Level'.

How could I add a tooltip on top of that?

Comment: Question: do you want the header AND the tooltip?  I ask because Bootstrap has a tooltip built in, but it seems to be scraping the title instead of data-original-title - just trying to find out if this will work for you.

Comment: Yeah, actually I need the header and tooltip since they will contain different text :)

Comment: I think I've got you covered.  See the answer and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a convenient javascript tooltip built right in.

Adjust your markup:

```
<select id="dropDownList" 
        class="selectpicker" 
        title="Show Level" 
        multiple 
        data-actions-box="true"
        data-placement="top" 
        data-toggle="tooltip">
    <option>Hello!</option>
    <option>Hello Again</option>
</select>
```

--

`data-placement` can be "top" "right" "left" or "bottom"

Then, in javascript, target the element and call the tooltip function, like so:

```
$('#dropDownList').tooltip().attr('data-original-title', 'Here We Are!');
```

This is where you need to set what the text in the tooltip is.  Normally, you'd set it in the actual markup with the `title` attribute, or the `data-original-title` attribute **however** - if the `title` attribute exists in the markup it will ignore `data-original-title`.  Setting it in javascript I found to be a handy workaround (since you do need the title attribute for something else).

Here's a bootply to see it in action:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/D8lat0agCe) -- **NOTE**: please ignore the css.  I only put it in there to move the options box off the edge of the screen.

**EDIT 2**

I changed it to use the ID.  This is the best way to approach it so you can control what tooltip is displayed on what item.  Otherwise, all tooltips will be the same.  Here is the updated [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QCnMMM30mF)

Comment: This is almost working fine but if I use the '.selectpicker' class, then the tooltip gets added to other dropdowns that I have on my page. I tried to reference the item by using the ID but then it stopped working. Any idea? Also, by doing that, the header title disappear completely

Comment: try the new javascript

Comment: Wait- when you tried grabbing it by the ID, did you remember the pound sign?  #dropDownList?

Comment: Yeah, i added the pound too :) http://jsfiddle.net/ug4gj8tx/11/ this example based on your answer seems to work fine but when I put it on my app, it does not shows the tooltip up. Extrange...  Actually, on the example I added here, the dropdown does not really populate but it appears on a box at the right. No clue why :)

Comment: Ahhh - you're using other javascript on that element?  I bet there's some sort of conflict going on between the two.

Comment: Yeah, it works now with your solution! Marking it as good. thanks!